# What is Story Point

Tags: project-management, agile

I was going through the definition of Velocity of a project. As per my understanding its the number of story points acheived vs planned in an iteraction.
I am not clear on what is a story point?

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it's about project management, not programming.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Story Point is an "arbitrary" unit of work assigned to a particular task or story.

It can be the number of man-hours the team (or the team leader) estimated the task/story would take,  but it could be just any other unit of work/time.
The specific unit used for a Story Point is somewhat arbitrary in a sense that it doesn't even need to translate into a precise amount of man hours (or of work days or what not).  The only requirement is that the **Story Points reflect the estimated amount of a work each task or story will require *in a consistent fashion***.

If the story point are assigned in such a consistent fashion, story points become a useful metric for measuring progress on the overall project.   Also, if the amount of work programmers can perform during a given span of time (say during a 2 weeks "sprint") is expressed in story points, it is possible to plan the list of stories that can be delivered during the sprint (if all goes well ;-) )

Answer (score 2):

A story point is something used by the scrum to estimate work effort on a story. It's an arbitrary measure such as person-hours, or a simple `{easy-peasy, one-for-the-graduate, medium, guru, crikey-thats-a-toughie, near-impossibility}` (`{1, 3, 9, 27, 81}` sort of thing) selection.

Hence a fairly simple story (hello, world) might be one story point, while a more complex one (a Facebook clone) would be many more.

Really good teams will maintain a history of stories and their points (both estimated and actual).

That way, you can just go find an earlier story similar to the one you're estimating and use its *actual* point count (found once the story had finished) as a baseline for the current story.

See [this entry in the Agile FAQ](http://agilefaq.wordpress.com/2007/11/13/what-is-a-story-point/) for more detail, or [the top page](http://agilefaq.wordpress.com/) for lots of other goodies.

Answer (score 0):

It is the complexity of story that is used to measure the team velocity. Normally, it is not precised hours the story will need because you can't know specially when you are a new agile team. But with time you will be able to more precisely assign a number to story because you learn with time.

Since main purpose of point is to get an estimation to measure your speed therefore you keep in mind the complexity of story (e.g, implementation time + team skills + knowledge + experience in the domain ,etc )